# How to avoid putting std::string in exception class?

Tags: c++, exception

Here is my exception class:

```
class Win32Failure : public std::exception
{
public:
    Win32Failure( char const* win32_function_name, LONG error_code );

    char const* win32_function_name() const { return win32_function_name_; }
    LONG error_code() const { return error_code_; }

    virtual char const* what() const;

private:

    std::string GetFormattedMessage() const;

    char const* win32_function_name_;
    LONG error_code_;
    std::string error_text_;
};

Win32Failure::Win32Failure( char const* win32_function_name, LONG error_code )
    : error_code_(error_code)
    , win32_function_name_(win32_function_name)
{
    std::stringstream error_msg;
    error_msg   << win32_function_name << " failed with code: "
                << error_code << " (" << GetFormattedMessage() << ")"
                ;

    error_text_ = error_msg.str();
}

std::string Win32Failure::GetFormattedMessage() const
{
    TCHAR message_buffer[1000];

    FormatMessage(
        //FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        error_code_,
        0, // Default language
        reinterpret_cast<LPTSTR>(&message_buffer),
        sizeof(message_buffer) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        NULL
        );

    return std::string(message_buffer);
}

char const* Win32Failure::what() const
{
    return error_text_.c_str();
}
```

The [boost exception guidelines](http://www.boost.org/community/error_handling.html) recommend not placing any objects that allocate memory as members of my exception class. In this case, the usage of `std::string` violates this. I respect the rule for this, however I can't think of a way to implement the `what()` override without using std::string to manage the memory (versus requiring the caller to manage it for me).

I could use a fixed-size buffer as a member and use C library functions (like `snprintf()`) to do the job, but this isn't very idiomatic to C++ and thus not an ideal solution.

Is this a suitable implementation of an exception class? If not, what improvements can be made?

Comment: The guidelines suggested calculating `what` on demand.

Comment: @PeterWood Yes, but that doesn't change the fact that the string being returned from `what()` needs to have a greater lifetime than the scope of `what()` itself. How will I manage that memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For what it's worth, all of the exception types defined in `<stdexcept>` take `std::string` as arguments. This could be interpreted by the library designers that it is "ok". I think the main argument against this is if you're in a memory constrained environment, you may not be able to allocate memory to throw your exception.

Comment: And then that an exception could be thrown whilst throwing an exception.

Comment: Looking at my implementation of `stdexcept` (g++ 4.1.2), there's no tricks - there's a `std::string` member named `_M_msg` in, for example, `std::logic_error`.

Comment: it has been pointed out to me that `std::exception` is not required by the spec to hold any strings, and that most derived classes contain a `std::string`.  Comments retracted.

Comment: `std::exception` is abstract, with `what` being a pure virtual, returning a `const char*`. I'd agree it's a bad idea invoking something that could throw when you are, yourself, attempting to throw, but it's exceedingly difficult to provide textual meaningful context without a heap alloc, which may fail. Also note that none of the standard exception types have marked their constructors as `throw()` (looking  pre C++11). Strictly speaking, throwing during construction of an exception is not throwing within an exception - the throw does not commence until the expression being throw has evaluated.

Comment: @PeterWood: The only reason I could think of that it could be a problem is if you catch the exception by value. If you catch it by reference, as everyone suggests that you do, you should be fine. Exception objects are not copied unless you specifically do so (by catching by value or by explicitly copying them). Thus, no memory is allocated during the *throwing* of an exception. Remember: `throw` doesn't execute until what it's throwing has finished being constructed.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, it could be a problem if you catch the exception by value.

Comment: The std subclasses of std::exception do not actually have members. At least not in the MSVC implementation. By looking at the headers directly, all they do is call the parent class constructor thusly: `std::runtime_error(const std::string &s) : std::exception( s.c_str() ) {}`

Comment: @xaviersjs, Standard C++ does not provide `std::exception` with any constructor overloads - it is an abstract class. Anything MSVC provides is non standard, and does not contradict my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions should guard against possible resource depletion during their construction. Using dynamic arrays in exceptions is no good (unless, it's done through pointers and there is a fall back plan if allocation fails). Using `std::string` to convey some information to user is doubly so: first of all, it's dynamic array, second it's useless mostly - function that throws exception does not know circumstances to try and explain reasonably why it failed.

Exceptions should do useful things like stack tracing + function parameters recovery (if possible) + ID to a external message (dynamic library resource, for example) in case there is need for formatted low-level message for end-user. If exceptions makes to the end-user it should make it in the form of coherent formatted error message from an external string table template (possibly, adding some run-time parameters). If exception is used to help debugging and makes it to the developer, then stack trace, function parameters, state of machine is useful, some hard-coded general string is not.

EDIT: It looks like you are trying to make C++ exception wrappers around Windows API calls, am I correct? If so, you should consider several things:

- using [_set_se_translator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to handle SE like C++ exceptions;
- using `dbghelp.dll`'s [StackWalk64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SymFromAddr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and similar functions to generate human-readable stack trace (just address are useful as well, for debugging offsite) in exception constructor;
- using an inline generic wrapper to check for error condition, returned by Windows API, that throws exception on specified condition or forwards the returned value as its return type. Just make sure there is no overhead (templates+inline+rvalue references eliminate overhead completely; also, make sure you DO NOT throw exception from checker function directly, delegate it to non-inline function to avoid compiler overhead for functions that throw exceptions explicitly).

Comment: Good information. I'm just a bit disturbed that the `what()` function is mostly useless, I wonder why I even inherit from `std::exception` at all. Essentially none of the base class interface is useful for me. Seems better just to have my own base exception type that does not derive from `std::exception`.

Comment: @RobertDailey You inherit from `std::exception` so users of your library (developers) can catch any exception that your library throws by catching `std::exception`... You don't have to derive from `std::exception`, it's for potential user's convenience. For example, STL containers, such as `std::vector` use `try/catch` blocks when they create objects, but they do not expect constructors of those objects to throw `std::exception` or its derivative - `std` containers use `catch(...)`.

Comment: @RobertDailey Also, `what()` returns `const char *`. This can be a pointer to a C-string in read-only memory, loaded when module is loaded. It does not, necessarily, need to be a pointer to a dynamically allocated memory within exception object.

Comment: "function that throws exception does not know circumstances to try and explain reasonably why it failed." What? If you throw an exception because a file couldn't be found, you know that the file can't be found. I've written a lot of exception throwing code, and in virtually every case, I could provide *something* of use. It may not have all of the contextual info, but it can certainly same *something* of value.

Comment: @NicolBolas Could you provide something of value as text message at the point where exception is being thrown, that is not already specified by the exception type (class)+stack trace+string ID+error return code+possible parameters to the function etc? In my opinion, text cannot add anything, really. `bad_alloc`, if I'm correct, returns string `"std::bad_alloc"` on calling `what()`. And for a good reason: it cannot give any useful information - it does not know why there is no memory, it does not know if it's terminal and so on. Recovered function parameters give better insight.

Comment: @AzzA: That assumes that you make a special exception type for every possible exception. Also, that's a lot of parameters that are not exactly required by most exceptions. If you're putting all that stuff in there, you may as well put a string in it too. Lastly, a stack trace assumes that the exception leaves `main`; that's not always the case.

Comment: @NicolBolas Stack trace does not assume that exception leaves `main()` at all - exception constructor is the point of walking stack back, stack trace happens BEFORE exception is thrown, why leaving `main()`?

Comment: @AzzA: Is there some standard library function I don't know about that retrieves a stack trace, or are you using a special non-standard exception class? Stack traces are not part of an exception's data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8092/discussion-between-azza-and-nicol-bolas)

Answer (score 0):

as part of the class private data have a static char buffer (consider using TLS if multi-threading)

what() just returns a const pointer to this buffer.

in GetFormattedMessage() you fill in the buffer (just as you are currently doing) 
(and potentially convert from unicode/wchars if needed since you're dealing with TCHARs)

as a static class member, the buffer is preallocated on the stack prior to any exception happening.

you don't need to manage the memory as it's allocated on the stack.
you do however chew up 1000 bytes of stack space (normally, not a big deal)

there is however only 1 buffer to hold the error text, but at any given time only one your custom exceptions should exist (I think?)